# Socket error (An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket) on aiohttp function

Tags: python, windows, sockets, https, aiohttp

```py
async def simultaneous_chunked_download(urls_paths, label):
    timeout = ClientTimeout(total=60000)
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(5)    

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout, connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)) as cs:
        async def _fetch(r, path):
            async with sem:
                async with aiofiles.open(path, "wb") as f:
                    async for chunk in r.content.iter_any():
                        if not chunk:
                            break
                        size = await f.write(chunk)
                        if not indeterminate:
                            bar._done += size
                            bar.show(bar._done)
                    if indeterminate:
                        bar._done += 1
                        bar.show(bar._done)

        indeterminate = False
        total_length = 0
        tasks = []
        for url, path in urls_paths.items():
            r = await cs.get(url)
            if not indeterminate:
                try:
                    total_length += r.content_length
                except Exception:
                    indeterminate = True
            tasks.append(_fetch(r, path))
            verbose_print(f"url: {url},\npath: {path}\n\n")

        if not indeterminate:
            bar = progress.Bar(
                expected_size=total_length, label=label, width=28, hide=False
            )
        else:
            bar = progress.Bar(
                expected_size=len(tasks), label=label, width=28, hide=False
            )

        logger._pause_file_output = True
        bar.show(0)
        bar._done = 0
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        logger._pause_file_output = False
        bar.done()
```

The function I have above is for downloading a dictionary of urls asynchronously and then printing out a progress bar. An example of its usage:

[image: Example]

The code itself runs perfectly fine, however i keep getting these errors:

[image: error]

Whilst benign, they are an eyesore and could point towards my lack of knowledge on both http and asynchronous code, so i would rather try and get it fixed. However im at a loss on where or what is causing it, especially as i like i said the code runs perfectly fine regardless.

If you would like a more practical hands on attempt at recreating this the full code is on my github repo on the dev branch: https://github.com/ohitstom/spicetify-easyinstall/tree/dev

Most of the program can be disregarding if you are testing this out, just press the install button and the problematic code will show itself towards the end.
Bare in mind this is a spotify themer so if you have spotify/spicetify installed you will want to use a vm.

## **FIXED!:**

```py
# Create App
globals.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
globals.app.setStyleSheet(gui.QSS)

# Configure asyncio loop to work with PyQt5
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
loop = QEventLoop(globals.app)
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

# Setup GUI
globals.gui = gui.MainWindow()
globals.gui.show()
    
# Set off loop
with loop:
    sys.exit(loop.run_until_complete(globals.gui.exit_request.wait()))
```

```py
class MainWindow(QuickWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            name="main_window",
            ...etc
        )

        self.exit_request = asyncio.Event()
        ......etc
    
    def closeEvent(self, *args):
        self.exit_request.set()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asyncio and aiohttp have some problems when running a lot of tasks concurrently on Windows, I've been having a lot of problems with it lately.

There are some workarounds available, the ones I use most are:

```py
# set this before your event loop initialization or main function
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Or:

```py
loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(your_main())
```

Comment: A variation of this did the trick. As its pyqt5 i couldnt exactly follow the same stuff.
The code i ended up using is at the bottom of the question now.